# How to manage data for the tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I have only one account - admin by default. I need to change user permissions to non-admin one. I believe that I have few options available (not great yet can be used)

1. Create a new endpoint on a server just for testing - to make it possible for non-admin user to update those permissions. This idea seems pretty odd to me to change something like that.
2. Have multiple users to be able to switch between them for different roles (all in all not that simple for now).
3. Connect to db within tests and make those changes on db - probably easiest option

Is it OK to create new endpoints for testing e.g. `/publish-cypress`? Is it OK to populate the database just for tests by running some operations on db?

Comment: The auto-generated comment isn't very useful in these cases - it should say something like don't "don't just re-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/72524552/3001761".

Answer (score -1):

On my personal opinion you shouldn't create testing endpoint.

What you should be testing is the method that will be called by these routes (Your service), and for front-end you can 'fake' these call to the api.

The simplest way to do that is to use something similar ton interfaces (you might want to look at typescript ;) )

An example to fake these calls in your tests:

I'll go with typescript as it'll be mush easier to understand (less code)

```typescript
//here you define all calls possible to your api
//dont forget to always pass the gateway by reference so that you can change whenever you want between fake & real
interface MyGateway {
   changeUserPermission(userId, permissions);
}

//here do the actual implementation that will be used by your app
class MyApiGateway implements MyGateway {
   public changeUserPermission(userId, permissions) {
      //here is your real api call with fetch, axios or whatever
      fetch('http://example.com/perms')...
   }
}

//now you can do another implementation for testing purposes

class MyTestGateway implements MyGateway {
   //here you can return hard values or do whatever you want so that your app doesn't depends on you backend
   public changeUserPermission(userId, permissions) {
      console.log(`Updating ${userId} is ${permissions}`);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you got it !
I rarely test infrastructure as i'm doing the exact same this in backend for repositories (interface that will communicate with the database) so you can fake theses too.

A really quick implementation would be with a Map (id - object/value)

On another note if you do wish to test your infrastrucure (DB) you should look for mocks & fixtures